# How to set minimum friends to invite on a facebook app

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

i have this piece of code that works perfectly when inviting friends,

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
appId:'APP_ID',
cookie:true,
status:true,
xfbml:true

});

function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'Your Message diaolog'

});
}
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
if (top.location!= self.location)
{
top.location = self.location
}
</script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();"> 
Facebook Invite Friends Link
</a>
```

how can I set the minimum number of friends invites in order for the dialog to close?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Making it a **requirement** to invite friends to move further into a facebook application is strictly forbidden by policy and, in all honesty, they'll just be marked as spam. Enough of that will get your app removed.